# I have read many resources and tried to find answer to my question but couldn't. I'm asking about how chaining the higher order functions work

Tags: javascript, higher-order-functions, arrow-functions

So, this is simple arrow function, but I don't understand how if sth, sth1, etc, works or what are they? Are they arguments as function or just value? or can be both of them? if does, how this chaining works, pls help me out.

```
const someFunction = sth => sth1 => sth2 => {
  // do something if needed
}
```

Comment: This looks like a weird exercise in figuring out operator order precedence. You get 3 variables which all refer to the same arrow function (taking a single argument)

Comment: isn't it possible to have also functions?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. There is one arrow function expression within that whole snippet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have there isn't really chained arrow functions (or [currying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36314/what-is-currying?noredirect=1&lq=1)), but a very confusing way of assigning the same function to multiple identifiers at once.

`=` evaluates from right-to-left, and the whole expression evaluates to the value on the right-hand side. The rightmost side of the assignment is the arrow function expression:

```
sth2 => {
  // do something if needed
}
```

There, `sth2` is an argument.

The arrow function gets assigned to an identifier named `sth1`:

```
sth1 = sth2 => { ...
```

`sth1` hasn't been declared yet. This will either throw an error if you're in strict mode, or it'll put a property on the global object with a value of the arrow function in sloppy mode.

Then, that whole section evaluates to that arrow function, and the process repeats itself for `sth`.

```
sth = theArrowFunction
```

Finally, *that* assignment evaluates to the arrow function, and the identifier `someFunction` is created that contains the arrow function.

A less confusing way of accomplishing the same thing (in either strict or sloppy mode) is

```
sth1 = sth2 => {
  // do something if needed
};
sth = sth1;
const someFunction = sth1;
```

But *are you sure* that's the exact code you're using? If your code was actually

```
const someFunction = sth => sth1 => sth2 => {
  // do something if needed
}
```

then that's not chained assignment, but [currying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36314/what-is-currying?noredirect=1&lq=1), where `sth`, `sth1`, and `sth2` are all arguments for different functions.

Answer (score 1):

This is equivalent to:

```js
const myFun = x => {...}
const sth1 = myFun
const sth = sth1
const someFunction = sth
```